# Creating object reference in prototype constructor

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-programming

I'm trying to wrap my head around using Javascript prototype objects and have run into a block perhaps due to my understanding of a traditional classes.

My code looks like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var instance = new cards();
    $dom = instance.buildItem(5);
}
var cards = function () {
    //constructor
    this.chromaObj = chroma.scale(["lightblue", "navy"]).domain([2, 6]);
}
cards.prototype.buildItem = function (val) {
    var scale = this.chromaObj;
    var $item = $("<span>" + val + "</span>").addClass("label-default").addClass("label").css({
        "background-color": scale(val)
    });
    return $item;
}
```

Every time scale is called in the buildItem function, I receive an error in the console that scale is not a function, however, if I create the scale instance inside of the buildItem function, it works as expected.

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to why I am unable to access the function reference when it is defined in the constructor?

Comment: because scale is not a function. change `this.chromaObj = chroma.scale(["lightblue", "navy"]).domain([2, 6]);` to `this.chromaObj = chroma.scale` which means you are assigning function reference.

Comment: check if `chroma.scale(["lightblue", "navy"]).domain([2, 6])` returns a function

Comment: Chroma uses a method chaining pattern, so all of those functions I am calling should return a new instance and a call to `this.chromaObj(val)` should make a call to the chroma constructor. I want to assign the specific `scale(["lightblue", "navy"]).domain([2, 6])` instance to chromaObj.

Comment: @YevhenTiurin Yes it does when called normally, but when called in the constructor, for some reason the variable is not being set to that function. If I use `var scale = scale(["lightblue", "navy"]).domain([2, 6])` in the buildItem function, it works correctly.

Comment: then try `"background-color": scale`

Comment: @vinayakj scale and this.chromaObj are undefined, I just do not understand why

Comment: That means `chroma.scale(["lightblue", "navy"]).domain([2, 6])` is not returning anything.

Comment: I have confirmed that it is returning the appropriate function by stepping through the code in the debugger. For some reason the `this.chromaObj` is not being set properly as a reference to that returned function.

Comment: @phosplait, can you provide sampel jsfiddle?

Comment: @phosplait, seems your code work ok: http://jsfiddle.net/L3edvbm8/

Comment: This question doesn't show enough information to replicate the error, so it can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

The original code does in fact work correctly.

My problem turned out to be that I was calling `buildItem` from another method (not shown here) using the generic `cards.prototype.buildItem()`, which caused a subsequent call to `chromaObj` to be undefined.

The solution was to change all calls to `cards.prototype.buildItem()` to `this.buildItem()`.